# How to add log4j (VM Arguments) while running testng runner on commandline

Tags: java, batch-file, selenium-webdriver

My testngRunner.bat file like below,

```
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\projectname
java -cp C:\Users\username\Desktop\projectname\javalibs\javalibs\*;C:\Users\username\Desktop\projectname\bin testng.TestNGRunner -executionPath C:\exection\executionPath -testngxml C:\Users\username\Desktop\projectname\testngxml\example-testng.xml
```

I can get the report on html format without log files, but I need to add the log4j argument for taking logs. Can you tell me anyone how we can add this argument on testNGRunner.bat file.

Logfile VMarugments like this.

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/\Users\username\Desktop\projectname\src\properties\log4j.properties
```

Thanks for advance helping this issue.